# How can i alternate this input?

Tags: java, stdin

I'm having some trouble with this Java input:

```
public class Testinput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        String[] name = new String[N];
        int[] year = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            name[i] = StdIn.readString();
            for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
                year[j] = StdIn.readInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(name[i]+" " +year[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For example: it needs to read name and age in an alternating order:

```
2
bob
1963
kelly
1981
```

and print:

```
bob 1963
kelly 1961
```

But instead it asks for an input of length 6 (instead of 2*N = 4) and prints out:

```
input1 input5
input4 input6
```

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: You only need one `for` loop for that. Inside that loop read both elements `name[i]` and `year[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you coming from C background where you are used to Char-array? In Java, it is much straight forward. You can input by String.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); //Create a scanner object

int n = scn.nextInt();           //Enter number of people you want to prompt and record
String[] name = new String[n];   //Create array of size based on n
int[] year = new int[n];         //Create array of size based on n

for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
    name[x] = scn.nextLine();    //for string inputs
    year[x] = scn.nextInt();     //for whole number
}
```

This will provide you an alternative for inputs.
Most universities and schools I encounter teaches their students to use Scanner for receiving user inputs. So you may want to use it too if you are allowed to.